# React JS Get Sum of Numbers in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sum

I have this array

```
const data = [
  {"One",prix:100},
  {"Two",prix:200},
  {"Three",prix:300}
]
```

and I want to get the sum of all those `prix` like this:

```
sum = 600
```

Comment: your objects in your array are invalid. Also, what have you tried so far and what issues are you facing?

Comment: Yes, every object has a key-value pair

Comment: reduce() executes  a function on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` :

```
data.reduce((a,v) =>  a = a + v.prix , 0 )
```

```js
const data = [
  {title : "One",prix:100},
  {title : "Two",prix:200},
  {title : "Three",prix:300}
]

console.log((data.reduce((a,v) =>  a = a + v.prix , 0 )))
```

Answer (score 8):

The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

```
arr.reduce(callback, initialValue);
```

reducer will only return one value and one value only hence the name reduce. Callback is a function to be run for each element in the array.

and Function arguments function(total,currentValue, index,arr):

```
Argument           Description

total              Required.The initialValue, or the previously returned value of the function
currentValue       Required.The value of the current element
currentIndex       Optional.The array index of the current element
arr                Optional.The array object the current element belongs to
```

in this example use this code:

```js
const data = [
  {title:"One",prix:100},
  {title:"Two",prix:200},
  {title:"Three",prix:300}
];

const result = data.reduce((total, currentValue) => total = total + currentValue.prix,0);

console.log(result);  // 600
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const sum = data.map(datum => datum.prix).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: well why using map you can reduce and add  like this `data.reduce((a, b) => a + b.prix,0)`

Comment: Separating `map` and `reduce` is more modular and doesn't require the initializer (`0`). It's also easier to refactor into a transducer or other functions with subsets/supersets of this functionality.